# Github- Redirecting users from www.username.github.io to username.github.io

Tags: github

I provided the wrong link to employers thinking my website link is www.username.github.io and checked its username.github.io. How can I redirect them to the correct page?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Try to ask github support how to deal with this situation, but I think you'll need to tell your employers to use the address without `www.` if they couldn't figure it out themselves.

Comment: I hope they do :( I already got a rejection haha guess too late :(

Comment: Sorry to hear. For future, provide url-shortener link, because those sites mostly have both `www.` and no `www.` websites, so you'd redirect them to a correct website. Good thing may be even using QRcode in your CV for example.